# Substracting coupon (discount) price from paypal form (if possible)

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have this eCommerce site where i am using paypal as the payment gateway. My problem is, on the form i need to show all the information of the cart including every items,shipping, tax, discount, coupon etc.. the adding part is easy, **the difficulty is substracting coupon price from the total price excluding shipping price**. It is possible in paypal to show all those contents and leave paypal to do the maths, as it does auto adds the items numbers and shipping . **I want paypal to substract the discount**.

HERE is my form

```
  <form method="post" name="paypal_form" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="the_email"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="the_url"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="the_url"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="the_url"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Eau De Toilette Spray (Tester) 3.4 oz"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="93.5"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Eau De Toilette Spray (Tester) 3.4 oz"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_2" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="93.5"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_3" value="Eau De Toilette Spray 1.7 oz"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_3" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_3" value="88"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_4" value="Eau De Toilette Spray 1.7 oz"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_4" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_4" value="88"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_5" value="Eau De Toilette Spray 3.4 oz"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="quantity_5" value="1"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_5" value="121"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="tax" value="50.40"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="100"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Click Here" id="sub">
  </form>
```

Please suggest me if anything is else is missing. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [discount variables](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/#id08A6HF080O3) to apply discounts to your cart.  This would still show all of the details on the PayPal payment page and show the discount being applied as well.